# Hooking message 0x202 in machine code and inspecting the associated window procedure?

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to figure out what my debugger does when I hit the pause button, so I decided to hook the WM_LBUTTONUP message (by inserting my own code after PeekMessageW and hitting an int3 if the message is equal to 0x202) so that I can see what commands run after that and how it differs from other messages/no message.

Unfortunately there appears to be no significant change in the code path, as it appears to just run "the message loop" either way and I can't find out how to get to where "`LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure()`" would normally be if I were looking at the code in C/C++. How do I get to that portion of the code in my debugger?

Comment: As an alternative, if you have a handle to the window that you are sending the message to you can use `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` to retrieve the address of the function.

Comment: The question makes little sense, a program cannot debug itself.  The debugger always runs in a different process.  What you see can only ever be related to the program you debug and not the debugger itself.  Debugging the debugger is not practical.

Comment: @HansPassant actually you can easily have one instance of a debugger debugging another instance of the same debugger, I've done this and successfully gained information about how my debugger works previously and it helped me solve an issue I was having previously.